# unable to left align the equations

Tags: equations, align

I see many example about aligning a set of equations to the left, but none them works for me. The set looks like

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
....
\begin{equation}
\begin{flalign}
A_{l-side} &= 1+2 \\
B_{both-side} &= 3+4+5+6  \\

\end{flalign}
\end{equation}
```

Then I get this error

```
 Runaway argument?
 A_{l-side} &= 1+2 \\ B_{both-side} &= 3+4+5+6 \\
 ! Paragraph ended before \flalign was complete.
 <to be read again>
               \par
 l.72

 ?
```

Who can interpret the error?!

Comment: The blank line inside of equation environments is not permitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like that

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{flalign}
   A_{l-side} &= 1+2&\\
   B_{both-side} &= 3+4+5+6
\end{flalign}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

I have only added an `&` at the end of the first line. Note that there should be no blank line inside the math environment.

---

Or may be that is what you want

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{flalign}
   &A_{l-side} = 1+2&\\
   &B_{both-side} = 3+4+5+6
\end{flalign}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

---

Or

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength\mathindent{0pt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{alignat}{2}
   &A_{l-side}&& = 1+2\\
   &B_{both-side} &&= 3+4+5+6
\end{alignat}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: But the equations are not left aligned. Are they?

Comment: I have added another suggestion. But I am not sure if I unterstand what you want.

Comment: Originally I was looking for the second case. But now I see that third case is the best. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

(1) do not use `equation` around it, (2) typo, you have two `\begin{flalign}`

Comment: post has been updated

Comment: Removing `\begin{euqation}` and `\end{equation}` has o effect also

Comment: Never use blank lines inside math envs. Not supported.